# Is it possible to destructure an array type into its elements as a type parameter?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Amended with a minimal example. [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-QS5BiUWj+bClTHLBDMKAJqA6MQ3tIYXCxBoOhT1QbbKVQHkgXrXLYig0I18DsjNWx0Mlutw0kS5Kh1m9UB8Uiw8PhoHJIHT0GXG-AmIjIkkUulekVSkFy5g6UxuJgKKv4WDs0DzNxIABCBKFQoNStuZdyVcdLo9SRVbdaxHEPeIAeR6RHMD7hmA7hUjSdLxNaGIOGCGJcCwUJZiSJx5KILDRrG8aEtOKA8OC8BfGySaaoeFKjugRiOJOqB0Ao8AJuIDp5nIRZYmSGZ9lqRFsg2VZLvhDCovS5aGNsXLkvEABKMbmJAvgAAp+vsdh+GatiigkiIJOKASigADOKkiqXG6kiJpi46XpBmigAjAZNahI8ySpGkBRSru+6HseCSnoewKXjed6sY874ZvE37TD5gF+SB1QaPaOhKGIxBsvEAAiBzwOgdDdHQmrwNmJh5Y4hi0LCvoWYgGnvKggnPoiZZ-oYAgznOQryV2Sk5ecBXwEViAqWpdVWb4WnwLZcj6QE80uQyEZRhQmA8ESGK0P6nzfH8AKGMQeCYKGKC4hQw3vHQhhAgIlVRiRsBkWgY50Q1mIFmgjHdAmGKHcdV45vSACQ7npF5P5xUB-mBeeIW3oU4URJF3TRSgsV-gBUOJQjDLrOY8TYMQFAQxj+5Avyr6E1cyUNGxkbyIG0BpLm-7qXgAmcSWGIXidwXoKhBEssxYKAxCbYALRHEObHUVEElGC0A5Tp1VnFKEOgRYuL4rLYkgdbOVmikytiSi2YAKkAA)

```
// Adapted from https://github.com/abalabahaha/eris, licence MIT

// Not exported
interface ClientEvents<T> {
    (event: "ready", listener: () => void): T;
    (event: "connect", listener: (id: number) => void): T;
    (event: "error", listener: (message: string) => void): T;
    // needed or TypeScript will take the one above as the definition in the first example
    (event: string, listener: (...args: any[]) => void): T;
}

export declare class Client {
    on: ClientEvents<this>;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Separate module

// The declarations above are expected to be used like this
const client = new Client();
// Types are correctly inferred for each handler
client.on("ready", () => console.log("hello world!"));
client.on("connect", id => console.log(id));

// Example: this falls back to the generic declaration and all typings are lost for each function,
// unlike directly calling Client.on above
const listeners: Record<Parameters<Client["on"]>[0], Parameters<Client["on"]>[1]> = {
    ready: () => console.log("hello world!"),
    connect: id => console.log(id)
}

// Missing: Destructure to extract the parameters of Client.on
const handlers: Record<Destructure<Parameters<Client["on"]>>> = {
    // The goal is that TypeScript should figure out what the typings for each of these functions should be
    ready: () => console.log("hello world!"),
    connect: id => console.log(id),
    error: msg => console.warn(msg)
};

// Then maybe something like this would work and still be type-safe
// for (const event in handlers) {
//     client.on(event, handlers[event]);
// }
```

ORIGINAL BEFORE EDIT

Situation: `Eris.Client.prototype.on` is a method that accepts two arguments.

I have managed to declare a type `Record<Parameters<Eris.Client["on"]>[0], Parameters<Eris.Client["on"]>[1]>`, but separated arguments mean that any relationship between the arguments isn't captured and both fall back to their most generic. That is, if the type of the second argument can be narrowed based on the type of the first argument, this cannot capture it and the typing extracted here is the union of all possible types.

Is it possible to implement some kind of type `Destructure` so I can declare a type `Record<Destructure<Parameters<Eris.Client["on"]>>>`?

Comment: Can you simplify this into a [mcve]?

Comment: My apologies, I've amended the original submission now.